# Display all the columns in employees table along with average salary of each dept

Tags: sql, oracle

i want a query to display all the columns in employees table along with average salary of each department.

Answer (score 4):

Considering that all the details like `salary`, `department_id` present in the `employees` table, you can use `AVG` `analytical function`:

```
SELECT
    E.*,
    AVG(E.SALARY) OVER(
        PARTITION BY E.DEPARTMENT_ID
    )
FROM
    EMPLOYEES E
```

Cheers!!